Hosting on Azure Container App HTTPS problem
I created a Azure Container App with a Nginx web server. My site is running and does everything as expected. There is just 1 thing I'm not able to work as expected. I added a custom domain with a managed certificate. So when i'm visiting my site, it responds with https://azure.mydomain.be. But when i'm in the settings or checking the logs it's showing http://azure.mydomain.be.
I'm not sure how to fix this and if i'm able to fix this.
my nginx server is configured like this:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    root /var/www/html/web;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    
   # All the other stuff necesery for Drupal
}

I tried a nginx configuration with port 443, but that doesn't work, since I need to add a path for the certificates. But since I'm using the managed certificate from Azure, I can't add these.
I installed the drupal module Security Kit and set these settings under SSL/TLS, but that didn't help:

HTTP Strict Transport Security
Include Subdomains

I also tried a return 301 https://azure.mydomain.be in nginx, but got me too many redirects error
